# Android intent filters to catch app crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Does somebody know intent filter for Android app crashes or even system log? 
I want to catch up any crashes that happen on device by broadcast listener and save it to database.
Any other ideas how to catch up in my app any other apps crashes will be also very helpful. 
Thank you!